# What is a word/ expression for a cut down said with a grin?

Tags: phrase-requests, expressions, idioms, idiom-requests

When someone is grinning at you while cutting you down. A snide comment is the best I have found. Or cheshire cat grin. There has to be a better word for this common occurrence.

Comment: Are you looking at something like “mocking”?

Comment: What sort of grin? An evil grin that makes it worse, or a friendly smile that softens the effect? (Also, do you want a noun, verb, adjective...)

Comment: The use of "cut down" as a noun is unfamiliar to me, and I find myself wondering if you meant "put down"?

Comment: There are lots of possibilities depending on your relationship and the context.

Comment: Wow, thank you all for giving my question your thoughts! I definitely mean being put down  while the person putting me down is smiling at me. The thought has never entered my mind while watching the person’s face that they were trying to soften the evilness coming out of their mouth with their smile. More like they enjoyed putting me down and it was showing on their face. I just don’t know how to describe this common event. I work in the very cutthroat world of emergency nursing where the egos are huge if that helps give some context to the environment in which it is happening.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is **sardonic**:

> *sardonic* [adjective]: disdainfully or sceptically humorous: derisively mocking ...
>
> the word implies scorn, mockery, or derision that is manifested by
> either verbal or facial expression.
>
> ...
>
> - *a sardonic comment* ...
> - *surveyed the scene with a sardonic smile*

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sardonic)]

Answer (score 0):

Try these words: [gloating](https://www.wordnik.com/words/gloating) or [smug](https://www.wordnik.com/words/vindictive#:%7E:text=adjective%20Disposed%20to%20revenge%3B%20prompted,adjective%20obsolete%20Punitive.)